# Python: Insert QByteArray to SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to store image data (screenshots) in SQLite database.

```
now = int(math.floor(time.time()))
ba = QByteArray()
buff = QBuffer(ba)
image.save(buff, format)
params = (str(ba.data()), "image/%s"%format, now, url)
s_conn = sqlite.connect("cache/screenshots_%s.db"%row['size'])
s_curs = s_conn.cursor()
s_curs.execute("UPDATE screenshots SET data=?, mime=?, created=? WHERE filename=?", params)
```

This code gives me error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
Any manipulation with QByteArray (incl. converting it to Qstring) gives me this error, or ascii to utf-8 conversion error.
I've Googled this issue for about 2 days and every advice was incorrect for me.
How can I work it around?

Comment: First, specify which line causes the error. A full traceback would help. Then, (and assuming the last line) try changing each parameter in `params` to `""`, one at a time, to pinpoint the broken one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you are trying to store binary as a string by calling str(ba.data).  If you do this then it will not be a valid string and will cause endless grief for you later.  Behind the scenes SQLite uses Unicode for all strings.  However it does not check that a provided string is valid unicode (UTF8/16).  Consequently you can insert binary garbage pretending it is a string but when trying to retrieve it will fail dismally since it won't convert to Unicode.

SQLite has a binary type (named BLOB) and that is exactly what you should be using.  The way you provide a binary/blob binding is dependent on the SQLite wrapper you are using.  It looks like you are using PySQLite or SQLite 3.  For Python 2 use buffer and for Python 3 use bytes.

```
# Python 2
params=( buffer(ba.data()), ...)
# Python 3
params=( bytes(ba.data()), ...)
```